# SignalR Create Timer

Tags: signalr-hub

I am developing some code with SignalR .

I want to create one timer and this timer thick one Function and this Function read data from database by userName and get news belongs to caller .

Problem is If I creat Timer in Hub Class on every connection timer created again so this is unuseful.

If I create timer like that

```
   public class SignalRTime
{
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    private int _count = 0;

    private readonly static Lazy<SignalRTime> _instance = new Lazy<SignalRTime>(() =>
        new SignalRTime(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TimerHub>().Clients));

    private SignalRTime(IHubConnectionContext clients )
    {
        Clients = clients;
        _timer = new Timer(UpdateTime, null, 0, 6000);
    }


    private void UpdateTime(object state)
    {
        lock(CurrentTime)
        {
            _count++;
        }
        Clients.All.broadcastTime(CurrentTime);
    }

    public static SignalRTime Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }

    private IHubConnectionContext Clients
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string CurrentTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _count.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

At this situation I cannot Read Current UserName because HttpContext.Current is null despite I am  logged.

I do not know what I do .

Thanks For Help

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do in this class but in general you should have a separate timer class (not a hub class) and then use the ConnectionManager to invoke methods on  your hub class.

Comment: This class is seperate class , and timer works correctly but I can not reach current Username from this class.

Comment: So that is not really a SignalR issue. You need to see how to use session management and auth in asp.net applications and how you can retrieve the current username. Once you have the username, you can use GetHubContext to access the relevant methods.

Comment: In fact this is SignalR issue because when I create Instance with Lazy<> SignalR clear All Session , so I could not reach any  session context .And SignalR has own session context and I could not reach it from different class . So because SignalR clear Web Session, I could not reach username and above class does not work.And I can not create timer in Hub Class,If I do that signalR creates new  timer on every connection.